# Como mudar o valor ter de uma labor em asp.net via javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

Preciso  mudar o `text` de uma `label` lado por Javascript  e depois recarregar  a página

Segue o código da label

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="ValorMax" Visible="false">10</asp:Label>
```

É preciso colocar neste botão o javascript

```
<input type="button" id="btn01" value="2" />
```

Preciso que quando o button de id="btn01" for clicado, mude o valor da Label id="ValorMax" de 10 para 20

É recarregue a página

Comment: Sugiro que confirme como tem o seu código, pois o que colocou aqui está incompleto a nível das etiquetas, faltando `<` e `>`. Para além disso é necessário que seja mais explicito no que quer fazer exatamente. Mudar o `text` para que valor ? Com base em quê ? Quando deverá ser feita essa troca ?

Comment: Não conheço ASP muito bem, mas se colocares `document.getElementById('ValorMax').textContent = 20;` na página, isso muda o valor?

Comment: Tem algum impedimento técnico de fazer essa ação via .net?

Comment: A sua pergunta, até um certo momento funciona, depois do `reload` da página é perdido o valor e voltar ser 10 novamente.

Answer (score 0):

> Citação

Quando o `asp:label` é renderizado, acaba virando uma `tag` "`span`" do `HTML`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#btn01').click(function(){
    $('#ValorMax').html(20);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<span runat="server" ID="ValorMax" Visible="false">10</span>

<input type="button" id="btn01" value="2" />
```

Tentei responder de forma direta sua questão pois sei que utilizará isto como exemplo para coisas mais complexas. Para recarregar a página é só executar o código abaixo, não coloquei no exemplo pois você não iria ver a mudança de valor.

```
location.reload();
```

Coloquei um `JQuery`, pois é recomendável usar pois agiliza o desenvolvimento, mas há a forma de fazer com `javascript` convencional sem o `Framework` `JQuery`.